# http-proxy-middleware doesn't work in react app

Tags: reactjs, proxy

I have proxy for one of my microservises with authentication apis

```
const {createProxyMiddleware} = require('http-proxy-middleware')
module.exports = function (app) {

app.use(
    '/auth',
    createProxyMiddleware({
        target: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth',
        changeOrigin: true,
    })
    );
};
```

When I try to fetch this api I receive 404 error

```
const LOGIN_URL = '/auth/login'    
const login = () => {
    if (validate()) {
        fetch(LOGIN_URL, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(formData),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
                },
                credentials: 'include',
            }
        ).then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                window.open("/", "_self")
            }
            return response.json()
        })

    }
}
```

If I understand proxies correctly, /auth/login have to turn into http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/login. But it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you are using http-proxy-middleway to proxy request from your frontend to your backend. so then however you have not specified the path Rewrite option in your in your CreateProxyMiddleware function.so then you need to rewrite the request path before sending it to the target as well.

if you need to rewrite `/auth/login` to `/api/v1/auth/login`,

ex:-

pathRewrite: `{'/auth':'api/v1/auth' //remove /auth and prepend /api/v1/auth}`

[Ref this link](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/master/recipes/pathRewrite.md)